Alternate measure of uncertainty: extropy
I have started studying extropy which is complementary dual of entropy. Entropy is defined as $E=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i\log p_i$ whereas extropy is defined as $Ex=\sum_{i=1}^n (1-p_i)\log(1- p_i).$
You can find the detail view in this paper.
It is given in the paper that extropy is an alternate measure of uncertainty. I go through the paper but I count get it that exxtropy actually measures what? As we know in entropy if entropy increases probability decreases and vice-versa, but what about extropy. What if extropy increases?
